# Show text and icon in the middle of a button

Tags: css

I am coding a button with html5 and css3. Here are how it looks in different sizes:[image]

You can see the icons are not in the middle. I know why it happens. But how can I set the icons in middle? Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" title="" class="blue-pill centered" role="button"><i class="icon">a</i><span>start</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.blue-pill {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 135px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #002032;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #1488ae;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #1488ae;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #1488ae;
}
.blue-pill .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #e57125;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.blue-pill span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.blue-pill.centered {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.blue-pill.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

I am using icon fonts for icons. Here is what I want:

[image]

Comment: that's not plain css3. Could you please include the relevant tag for this.

Comment: @Imrul.H use margin-top for the icon style

Comment: This is sass. but easily understandable.. :)

Comment: Mess with `vertical-align` and `line-height`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `vertical-align:middle` to `.blue-pill .icon` and `.blue-pill span`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcccycd2/)

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine! But I dont understand how. Because vertical-align:middle should only work for display:table-cell.

Comment: It is also used for aligning inline (or inline-block) elements against others of the same type in that container: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align.  vertical-align when used with a table cell means that the contents of the cell will be vertical aligned where as on an inline element it means that the element itself will be vertical aligned to the current line of text